# Keep toggle state after a php file is reloaded within a div?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I have a php file which parses a table and is loaded into a div:

```
<div id ="videprinter">
    <script type="text/javascript">
    $(function(){
        function load(){
        $("#videprinter").load("videprinter.php")
        setTimeout(css, 3000);;

    }   
    load();
    setInterval(load,60000);
    });
    </script>
</div>
```

I then have a button that can be clicked to hide all table rows that do not contain the word "PREM".

```
<input type='button' id='hideshowleagues' value='Hide Foreign Leagues'>

jQuery('#hideshowleagues').live('click', function(event) {        
        $("#videprinter table tbody tr:not(:contains('PREM'))").toggle();
    });
```

I have the set an interval of 60 seconds to reload the php file however every time it's reloaded the toggle state is reset and the rows that do not contain "PREM" are displayed again. How would I go about keeping the toggle state when the php file is reloaded without reloading the entire page?

Thank you very much.

Comment: load into a hidden element and toggle?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To follow on to Derek's comment you could use a hidden field or a global variable on the page to track the status of toggle. Then change code in videprinter.php to look at a URL parameter and filter results based on the url parameter.
    var tracktoggle = "no";

```
    //on your click event code toggle the variable
    jQuery('#hideshowleagues').live('click', function(event) {        
    $("#videprinter table tbody tr:not(:contains('PREM'))").toggle();
    if (tracktoggle == "no") {
        tracktoggle = "yes";
    }
    else {
        tracktoggle = "no";
    }
});

//in your load function add parameter to videprinter.php
$(function(){
    function load(){
    if (tracktoggle == "yes") {
        $("#videprinter").load("videprinter.php?loadprem=yes");
    }
    else {
        $("#videprinter").load("videprinter.php?loadprem=no");
    }
    setTimeout(css, 3000);;

}
```

Comment: Thanks, this helped. I used the code you suggested and then set the php file to filter using preg_match if the variable is set to yes, thanks again!